# How can i store several iphone contacts in sqlite3 table

Tags: ios-simulator, new-operator, field, abaddressbook

I developed an iPhone app which displays iPhone AddressBook contacts list. 
I want to add extra fields to the selected contact.

Using AddressBook framework,it was not possible.So,i want to attach those values to the "contacts" table of my database.

How can i insert those existing contacts into sqlite table(contacts).
Please,help me with a sample code.

Thanks in Advance,

Ramya.